# Unreal Engine (C++) или Unity (C#)?

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, unreal-engine-4

Я учусь на втором курсе информатики. И теперь я столкнулся с трудным вопросом. Какую дорогу выбрать? Я начал изучать C ++ на первом курсе, но начал думать о том, чтобы перейти на C # и начать с чего-нибудь попроще. Я много слышу о C ++, и это ужасно и сложно начинать. Итак, какой из этих двух путей я должен выбрать, чтобы стать GameDev?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This question may get closed soon, but if you choose to translate, it will surely be reopened, once the translation is done.

Comment: В любом случае на вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ

Answer (score 2):

Это беcсмысленный вопрос. Выбираешь между тёплым и мягким.

Малобюджетные и инди проекты делают на Unity, мобильные издатели даже не работают с другими. На Unreal или своих движках, которые тоже пишут на плюсах, делают крупные проекты. И это далеко не все пути, ещё есть бекэнд.

Ну и что для тебя такое это самое GameDev? Майнкрафт писали на Java... разве не GameDev? И даже на Python, не коммерческие конечно, но пишут.

Что касается "сложности" вопрос тоже особо не имеет смысла. Язык это инструмент, грубый, точный, удобный, они разные. Но какой бы он ни был, критерии хорошего кода одинаковые для всех и от языка к языку не меняются и как раз по этому оценивают разработчика. Хорошие программисты могут обозревать код на языках, на которых даже не пишут сами и сказать, что он полное говно или норм.